# How to update FlatList if data is updated

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-flatlist

The way I get the data is inside the componentWillMount method, its working fine when it renders the FlatList when the app boots up, but when I'm adding data, all I want is to update also my flatList. How can I do that here's the code snippet:

```
 componentWillMount() {
    console.log(`componentDidUpdate`, prevProps);
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if (user != null) {
      const db = firebase.firestore();
      const docRef = db.collection('userCheckInHistory').doc(user.uid);
      docRef
        .get()
        .then(doc => {
          if (doc.exists) {
            let shopId = this.props.shopId;
            let userShopHistoryData = doc.data();
            let userShopPick = userShopHistoryData[shopId];
              this.setState({
                checkInHistory: userShopPick,
                shopId: this.props.shopId
              });


          } else {
            console.log('No such document!');
            return false;
          }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log('Error getting document:', error);
        });
    }
  }
```

Now this is my FlatList code:

```
renderHistoryList() {
    const sortedData = Common.getArrayByObject(this.state.checkInHistory);
    if (this.state.checkInHistory !== '') {
      return (
        <FlatList
          data={sortedData}
          extraData={this.state}
          keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <MyListItem
              id={item}
              onPressItem={this._onPressItem}
              selected={!!this.state.selected.get(item)}
              title={item}
            />
          )}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return <Spinner />;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You could have a variable in `state` and update it when you add more data

Comment: @gaback thank you for your response, but can you please make an example?

Comment: Let say you have: `this.state = {....., updateDataTime: 0}; this.count = 0`. When you add more data, you add this lines at the end `const count += 1; this.setState = ({updateDataTime: count})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get your data from api set your state with that data. And then if you add data and setState, react native will rerender app and you will see your data on the list.

Comment: hmm, im calling my data inside componentWillMount, its like a firestore query, should I use redux to have a global state?

Comment: how can I call again that firestore call if its inside componentWillMount?

Comment: Put that call to another function and call that function. You dont need a global state just like this problem.

Comment: Another advice is you should call api in component did mount. Because if your app get response very quickly than react native didnt render the component yet. You will set data on noncreated component.